# HtmlUnitDriver doesn't get the page with BrowserVersion set to CHROME

Tags: jquery, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit

This is the code I wrote:

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
driver.get("http://localhost:8080/login.jsp");
```

If I don't set The BrowserVersion to CHROME I get the page correctly.
With the code I wrote I get this exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot find function attachEvent in object [object HTMLDocument]. (http://localhost:8080/js/jquery.js#865)
Build info: version: '2.32.0', revision: '6c40c187d01409a5dc3b7f8251859150c8af0bcb', time: '2013-04-09 10:39:28'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: HtmlUnitDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:367)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:346)
    at webapp.test.TestSuite.setDriver(TestSuite.java:59)
    at webapp.test.TestSuite.getDriver(TestSuite.java:77)
    at webapp.test.home.Home.setUp(Home.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot find function attachEvent in object [object HTMLDocument]. (http://localhost:8080/js/jquery.js#865)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:669)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:601)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:555)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadExternalJavaScriptFile(HtmlPage.java:1082)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:399)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$3.execute(HtmlScript.java:266)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:276)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:676)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:635)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1170)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1072)
    at org.cyberneko.html.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:206)
    at org.cyberneko.html.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:330)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3074)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2041)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:918)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:499)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:452)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:892)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:241)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:187)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:268)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:156)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:434)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:309)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:374)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:359)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function attachEvent in object [object HTMLDocument]. (http://localhost:8080/js/jquery.js#865)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3603)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3587)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3608)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3624)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFunctionError(ScriptRuntime.java:3688)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThisHelper(ScriptRuntime.java:2207)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2189)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1333)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:798)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:405)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:275)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3031)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:115)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:546)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:654)
    ... 49 more
```

For reference, jquery version is 1.8.1. The exception references this section of the jquery code:

```
jQuery.ready.promise = function( obj ) {
    if ( !readyList ) {

        readyList = jQuery.Deferred();

        // Catch cases where $(document).ready() is called after the browser event has already occurred.
        // we once tried to use readyState "interactive" here, but it caused issues like the one
        // discovered by ChrisS here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12282#comment:15
        if ( document.readyState === "complete" ) {
            // Handle it asynchronously to allow scripts the opportunity to delay ready
            setTimeout( jQuery.ready, 1 );

        // Standards-based browsers support DOMContentLoaded
        } else if ( document.addEventListener ) {
            // Use the handy event callback
            document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", DOMContentLoaded, false );

            // A fallback to window.onload, that will always work
            window.addEventListener( "load", jQuery.ready, false );

        // If IE event model is used
        } else {
            // Ensure firing before onload, maybe late but safe also for iframes
            document.attachEvent( "onreadystatechange", DOMContentLoaded );

            // A fallback to window.onload, that will always work
            window.attachEvent( "onload", jQuery.ready );

            // If IE and not a frame
            // continually check to see if the document is ready
            var top = false;

            try {
                top = window.frameElement == null && document.documentElement;
            } catch(e) {}

            if ( top && top.doScroll ) {
                (function doScrollCheck() {
                    if ( !jQuery.isReady ) {

                        try {
                            // Use the trick by Diego Perini
                            // http://javascript.nwbox.com/IEContentLoaded/
                            top.doScroll("left");
                        } catch(e) {
                            return setTimeout( doScrollCheck, 50 );
                        }

                        // and execute any waiting functions
                        jQuery.ready();
                    }
                })();
            }
        }
    }
    return readyList.promise( obj );
};
```

And specifically the line that triggers the exception is

```
document.attachEvent( "onreadystatechange", DOMContentLoaded );
```

which seems odd to me, since this line should be reached only

```
//If IE event model is used
```

What causes this exception?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem as yours but not exactly the same error. Just have a read on [HtmlUnitDriver documentation](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver) which might benefit to you. According to the documentation, the default JavaScript engine used by HtmlUnit is `Rhino`, although JavaScript is a well defined language by W3C, anyhow it has its own implementation which might not suit on a particular browser.

For my case, I'm using JSF but neither Chrome nor Firefox works for me. The test will only execute if I do is this `HtmlUnitDriver(true);`. Passing `true` into constructor is to tell the driver to mimic IE. If I insist want to do it in Firefox, I have to replace the `HtlmUnitDriver` with `FirefoxDriver`, then only the JSF execution will pass.

Hope this help.

Comment: The problem is I was using HtmlUnitDriver to simulate the behavior of different browsers in a "headless" environment. Replacing it with FirefoxDriver or ChromeDriver isn't going to help in this case.